# Confused about Android key event handling. Any good explanations?

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyevent

I'm a relative beginner with Android. Does anybody have a *sane* explanation for how to listen for keys and soft keys in an EditText/TextView?

I'd love to see a comprehensive tutorial or set of examples.

As I understand it, I can add a KeyListener to my Activity, e.g. onKeyDown(), onKeyUp() but when I try this I can't trigger the events for normal keys only HOME and BACK for example.

I have seen mention of using a TextWatcher but that isn't the same as handling raw key events.

There seem to be a number of half-solutions here on SO. Hoping you can help clear the mists of confusion...

Comment: The Android dev guide is a help... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign a key listener not to activity but rather to EditText itself.

Comment: That helps - one layer of mist gone!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have to listen to BACK or MENU key events. Simply add this method, without implementing any Interface. I do this in my BaseActivity, from which every Activity inherits.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(NAME, "Key pressed");

    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        Log.d(NAME, "Back pressed");
        // IGNORE back key!!
        return true;
        /* Muestra el Menú de Opciones */
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
        Intent menu = new Intent(this, Menu.class);

        // start activity
        startActivity(menu);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

PS: I highly discourage ignoring the back key.

Comment: Yeah - MENU and BACK work fine but KEYCODE_0, KEYCODE_1... and KEYCODE_ENTER don't trigger. I see code for onEditorAction which reacts to ENTER but do I have to trap that separately? Sorry if I confused you. I think your code is a good start... You have to consider repeats, cancels, longpresses etc. (depending on OS version). Still looking for a pointer to a comprehensive discussion.

Comment: IME operations are not generally raw key events; they are edit operations on an InputConnection that was retrieved from the current focus view.  (TextView/EditText has an implementation for editing its text).  You can get raw events *instead* by putting focus on a view that doesn't supply an InputConnection...  however this will significantly limit the functionality of the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
             if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
                //your code here
             }
         return false;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently found another way that be stuck using Activity `onKeyDown`, or event setting a key listener on view (which is not really working with key events from ADB in my case) with `view.setOnKeyListener`.

Since android `P` method `addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener` has been introduced. It allows you to do whatever you need to do when your view is able to catch unhandled key events.

Here is an example of how I used it :

```kotlin
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) yourView.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener { v, event ->
    when (event.keyCode) {
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN -> {
            TODO("Do whatever you need to do.")
            true // Specify you did handle the event
        }
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SOFT_RIGHT -> {
            TODO("Do whatever you need to do.")
            true // Specify you did handle the event
        }
        // etc...
        else -> false // Specify you didn't handle the event
    }
}
```